# "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-service, asp.net-core

Estou tentando comunicar minha aplicação com o web service do CadSus a partir de uma aplicação asp .net core. Tenho usando o código abaixo, mas sempre que tento recuperar o retorno da consulta recebo o erro "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'".

```
   var address = new EndpointAddress("https://servicos.saude.gov.br/cadsus/v5r0/cadsusservice");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

            var cad = new CadsusServicePortTypeClient(CadsusServicePortTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration.CadsusServicePort, address);//binding, address
            cad.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "-----------------------------";
            cad.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "---------------------"; 
            cad.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                                                    StoreName.My,
                                                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "");

            requestPesquisar itenspesquisa = new requestPesquisar();
            itenspesquisa.CNESUsuario = new CNESUsuarioType()
            {
                CNES = "*",
                Usuario = "*"
            };

            itenspesquisa.FiltroPesquisa = new FiltroPesquisa()
            {
                nomeCompleto = new NomeCompletoType { Nome = "*" },
                dataNascimentoSpecified = false,
                CPF = new CPFType { numeroCPF = "*" },
                tipoPesquisa = TipoPesquisaType.APROXIMADA
            };

            itenspesquisa.higienizar = false;
            ResultadoPesquisa[] resultWS = cad.pesquisarAsync(itenspesquisa).Result.responsePesquisar1;
            foreach (ResultadoPesquisa result in resultWS)
            {
                var teste = result.CNS;
            }
```

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possível solução é configurar sua aplicação no Web.Config ou App.Config da seguinte maneira:

Caso já exista uma configuração para o protocolo abaixo altere conforme linhas a seguir..

```
<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBindingConfig" />
    </protocolMapping>
```

Poderá ver mais detalhes desta solução no link abaixo:
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251134/the-http-request-was-forbidden-with-client-authentication-scheme-anonymous-err)